# Phonegap GPS plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, gps

I was using gps in my app from the html 5 and not the actual phonegap plugin it would seem.

I was getting some odd pop up on iPhone. I looked into the issue and got a little help from the phonegap google group:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/YKU-QdiDk5A
```

Basically my config.xml had the geo plugin twice and I was using the wrong version, and I was not using on device ready. Now I have fixed all that (or so I thought) and now I cant get GPS to work at all in Android.

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro" version="5.2.5">

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />

    <name>Beer Portfolio</name>
    <description>Know Your Beer</description>
    <author href="https://www.beerportfolio.glass" email="mike@beerportfolio.glass">Mike</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm"/>
    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" />


    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  - lower 4s -->
    <icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch - 5-5s -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPhone6-6+ -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.3" source="npm"/>
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm"/>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I have my javascript for my page that I want to use the GPS plugin start with:

```
$(document).on('deviceready', function () {
```

And I try and pull my GPS coordinates with:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        function showPosition(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

When I load the app on my phone nothing seems to execute on the page. I also try and start the page with this combination for on device ready, and it also didnt work:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("navigator.geolocation works well");
}
```

Any idas on why my GPS is not working?

Comment: I think you need to add the android namespace to your config header.  `<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" id="com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro" version="5.2.5">`

Comment: what does that do? My scanning plugin works fine without that

Comment: Wasn't the issue, I just solved it. Needed phonegap.js script tag in the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed one line of code in my HTML to fix this. I forgot to add:

```
<script src='phonegap.js'></script>
```